# Where should a root be located in your routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Probably something trivial but I was wondering where the root key word along with its controller action should be placed within the routes.rb file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

I've taken a look at a couple of tutorials and most of them seem to have it at the bottom. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root)

> You should put the root route at the top of the file, because it is the most popular route and should be matched first.

and the partial reasoning is

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified...

So, you want the most commonly used routes to be early on/high up in the file, so you don't have to go through and waste time checking a lot of uncommon or downright rare routes.